# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast from [Module "deployment.edge.war:main" from Service Module Loader]

Tags: java, jboss, hazelcast

I am getting this error as i have properly added the jars Hazelcast

```
  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast from [Module "deployment.edge.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoad
```

Comment: A bit too broad. Which Jboss are you using? Which runtime? Which kind of project builder are you using(maven, ant,gradle, nothing..)?

Comment: Is the hazelcast.jar in the WAR?